# How to format date colum in table ("dd/MM/yyyy")

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

Ng-zoro Component with anguluar : I want format date in table column, Has anyone worked with this component before please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I think that I guess what you want, but try to be more clear the next time...

Probably you need that:

```html
<td>{{ yourObject.date | date: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}}</td>
```

You can find more info there:
https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { NzDatePickerModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/date-picker';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import en from '@angular/common/locales/en';

registerLocaleData(en);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?